How to read a file with CreateFile in C++?
I can read a file with Unicode path like this:
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

///--- variables ---///
//-- DWORD --//
DWORD dwBytesToRead = 0;

//-- HANDLE --//
HANDLE hFileHandle;

//-- wchar_t array --//
wchar_t a_wcContentsOfFile[999999] = {0};

//-- WINBOOL --//
WINBOOL wbResult;

int main()
{
    hFileHandle = CreateFileW(L"D:\\Çağatay.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(hFileHandle != NULL)
    {
        wbResult = ReadFile(hFileHandle, a_wcContentsOfFile, 999999 - 1, &dwBytesToRead, NULL);
        if(wbResult != 0)
        {
            if(dwBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                a_wcContentsOfFile[dwBytesToRead + 1] = '\0';
                wprintf(L"%s\n", a_wcContentsOfFile + 1);
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hFileHandle);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

I have used this website as guideline:
https://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/windowsfileapis4_22.html
But I want to write contents of the file to wstring, not stdout.
How can I do this?

If you don't need something special from the WinAPI, why not use std::wifstream? Re: " I want to write contents of the file to wstring" - That's a one-liner using std::wifstream .

@TedLyngmo ifstream does not support non-ASCII paths. For example Ç and ğ are not ASCII.

Style note: comments that simply repeat the code aren't helpful. //-- HANDLE --// followed by HANDLE hHandle; is just distracting. Not to mention the name hHandle, which says nothing. Windows programs tend to use prefixes like h to describe the type of the variable (h stands for HANDLE), but many folks these days things that's just noise. With or without that prefix, though, give the variable a name that says what it does. hHandle should be something like fileHandle.

@PeteBecker I have already know that.

@ÇağatayKAYA What makes you think it doesn't support non-ASCII paths? std::wifstream is(std::filesystem::path(L"D:/Çağatay.txt")); and then std::wstring content(std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(is), std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>{}); - Done

@TedLyngmo I use Code::Blocks as IDE. But std::filesystem::path is a C++ 17 function.

Yes filesystem is from C++17. Are you using something older than C++17 for some reason? MSVC has an extension that lets you use std::wifstream is(L"D:/Çağatay.txt"); directly if that helps

@TedLyngmo I use MinGW as compiler for years. So, using MinGW / Code::Blocks is a kind of a habit for me. I tried Visual Studio years ago. Visual Studio is very huge IDE and installs tons of softwares to PC. But Code::Blocks is simple, small IDE.

@ÇağatayKAYA Ok, but if you have one of the recent MinGW distributions, it does support C++17

@TedLyngmo My question is about using CreateFile and ReadFile, not std::filesystem::path.

You are using windows file library. It is not std C++. At the very least, you must tag WIN32. Otherwise, don't complain about hints to us std::fstream or std::FILE.

@ÇağatayKAYA I understood your question. My suggestion would help you solve the problem in a modern way. Note that I did not provide an answer but fruit for thought. Why are you using CreateFile/ReadFile for operations that are standardized in C++?

ReadFile() has no concept of strings or Unicode, it only knows about raw bytes.
You already know how to read the raw bytes into a wchar_t[] array (assuming the file content is encoded in UCS-2 or UTF-16, that is). Simply assign that array to a std::wstring object afterwards, eg:
std::wstring wContent;

wbResult = ReadFile(hFileHandle, a_wcContentsOfFile, sizeof(a_wcContentsOfFile), &dwBytesRead, NULL);

if(wbResult != 0)
{
    wContent.assign(a_wcContentsOfFile, dwBytesRead / sizeof(wchar_t));
}

If you know the file size ahead of time (ie, from GetFileSize() or equivalent) then you don't even need the wchar_t[] array at all, you can presize the wstring and read directly into its data buffer, eg:
DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(ReadFile(hFileHandle, NULL); 

std::wstring wContent;
wContent.resize(dwFileSize / sizeof(wchar_t));

wbResult = ReadFile(hFileHandle, wContent.data(), wContent.size() * sizeof(wchar_t), &dwBytesRead, NULL);

if(wbResult == 0)
    dwBytesRead = 0;

wContent.resize(dwBytesRead / sizeof(wchar_t));

Also see: How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?, the solutions can be adapted for std::wstring.
